# mass insert non-ascii varchar into redis from mysql

Tags: mysql, redis

To mass insert into redis from mysql, see http://baijian.github.io/2013/10/12/import-data-from-mysql-to-redis.html.

Based on it, I met a problem when the mysql stored data those are not simple ascii charactor, e.g. Chinese text.

How can I archive this. I don't know if this problem happened on mysql or redis.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's all my fault.

I've checked my sql connection, the data are stored into mysql server in utf8 correctly, and the mysql client/connection/server are using utf8 encoding.

In this way, the data should be piped to redis-cli correctly.

I just coded wrong to produce the redis protocol.